# Broken image from mysql database using Longblob data type

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I see a lot of same question but have different codes from them, I used to find a solution where the only problem is to change it's datatype to "Longblob" but my datatype is already Longblob but have broken image. 
My `$pid` is set to this:

```
$pid=intval($_GET['id']);// get patient id
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `checkup_patient` WHERE patient_id='$pid' ORDER BY checkup_date DESC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {?> 
    <tr class="text-center">
    <td><?php echo $row['findings'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['treatment'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['pres_med_schedule'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['checkup_date'];?></td>
    <td>
        <img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($row['tblImage'])." /> //same code of others
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php  }?>
```

And here's my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#insert').click(function(){
                    var image_name = $('#image').val();
                    if(image_name == '')
                    {
                        alert("Please Select Image")
                        return false;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        var extension = $('#image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                        if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
                        {
                            alert('Invalid image file');
                            $('#image').val('');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: It might just be a 'typo' but there is a stray quote in this line: 
<img src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($row['tblImage'])."

Comment: Where is `$pid` set

Comment: @RiggsFolly it was set like this sir

Comment: $pid=intval($_GET['id']);// get patient id

Comment: It would have been better to include that in your question using the edit link

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 0):

As you are not within the PHP interpreter section i.e. `<?php ... ?>` then you will have to do:-

```
<img src="data:image;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['tblImage']);?>" />
```

Comment: I still have broken image sir.. Why is this?

Comment: What is contained in `$row['tblImage']`

Comment: while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
'tblImage' is the name of the value inside of my database sir

Comment: It is the picture that will saved from database sir.

Comment: Then  is the size of the BLOB fields big enough to hold ALL the image? Or could the image have been truncated when you saved it

Comment: I would have expected you to have saved the image to the DB as a base64 encoded string. Did you do that or did you just save the image as an image

Comment: No image displayed sir, just a broken image. And when I saved the image to the database it was displayed in the column like this "[BLOB - 6 B]"

Comment: I just saved an image as an image sir.

Comment: Image fiiles are complex and they often contain NULL BYTES which can be interpreted as EndOfFile by PHP and/or MySQL. I would bet that the image on your database is corrupted.

Comment: I see, can you suggest what solution to do to solve my problem sir?

Comment: Store the `base64_encode(the image)` to the database. Or better still save only the location on disk of the image to the database.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting sir, I'll take that. Even though I don't understand much the function of each but I have to study for my thesis.